# Crawl multiple unique items for a same name using scrapy

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I have to crawl the following [url](http://www.tripadvisor.in/ExpandedUserReviews-g297628-d4586370?target=215117024&context=1&reviews=215117024,215074712,214865502,214583572,214432858,213741823,213566899,212805908,212264200,212182224&servlet=Hotel_Review&expand=1), which basically contains reviews. all the reviews there, has a review writer name, title for a review, and a review itself.

I've chosen "python-scrapy" to do this task.

But the url mentioned is not the start url, I will be obtaining it from the basic `parse` method. And in parse I will initialize a `itemLoder`. I will extract few items there and pass the items via `meta` of the response. (the extracted field contains information such as hotel name, Address, pricing etc....)

I have also declared items, namely "review_member_name", "review_quote", "review_review"

There are more than one review in the page and the review id for an review can be obtained from the `response.url`. (shown in parse method below)

**since there are many reviews and all will share the same item name, the items get concatenated** which should not happen. Can anybody suggest me a way to solve this?

below is my source for parse_review.

```
def parse_review(self,response):
    review_nos = re.search(".*www\.tripadvisor\.in/ExpandedUserReviews-.*context=1&reviews=(.+)&servlet=Hotel_Review&expand=1",response.url).group(1)
    review_nos = review_nos.split(',') # list of review ids

    for review_no in review_nos:
        item = response.meta['item']
        #item = ItemLoader(item=TripadvisorItem(), response=response) - this works fine but I will lose the items from parse method
        div_id = "expanded_review_"+review_no
        review = response.xpath('/html/body/div[@id="%s"]'%div_id)
        member_name = review.xpath('.//div[@class="member_info"]//div[@class="username mo"]//text()').extract()
        if member_name:
            item.add_value('review_member_name', member_name)

        review_quote = review.xpath('.//div[@class="innerBubble"]/div[@class="quote"]//text()').extract()
        if review_quote:
            item.add_value('review_quote', review_quote)

        review_entry = review.xpath('.//div[@class="innerBubble"]/div[@class="entry"]//text()').extract()
        if review_entry:
            item.add_value('review_review', review_entry)

        yield item.load_item()
```

following is my items.json ("review_review" is being removed and the items from parse method too is removed)

`[{"review_quote": "\u201c Fabulous service \u201d", "review_member_name": "VimalPrakash"},
{"review_quote": "\u201c Fabulous service \u201d \u201c Indian hospitality at its best, and honestly the best coffee in India \u201d",  "review_member_name": "VimalPrakash Jessica P"},
{"review_quote": "\u201c Fabulous service \u201d \u201c Indian hospitality at its best, and honestly the best coffee in India \u201d \u201c Nice hotel in a central location \u201d", "review_member_name": "VimalPrakash Jessica P VikInd"}]`

And please suggest a good title for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a new `ItemLoader` before doing `add_value` on it; now you're creating one item, and adding new values to it again and again in the loop.

```
for review_no in review_nos:
    item = ItemLoader(item=projectItem(), response=response)

    ...

    yield item.load_item()
```

You can also use `.add_xpath` directly with the xpath you're supplying, and use `response.xpath` as the selector for the item when creating the `ItemLoader`, that way you can probably avoid all the if tests and let the load do what it should do: load items.

Comment: Yes, This does work fine. But one more issue.I will edit my question

Comment: @AshwinRao I'm not sure what your second question is supposed to be. If it's not related to the original issue, you're probably better off creating separate questions.

Comment: One thing that I can do is passing the details scraped from "parse" method as a simple dictionary. and then extracting those dictionary in "parse_review" and inside the for loop adding it to the item. But is there any other gentle way? Like creating a item loader in "parse" method itself.

Comment: sorry for the bad structuring of my question. I am not good at English. My second question is I have a itemLoader already defined and loaded with the required value in "parse". And in other method(basically callback), I want to use that item in a for loop as shown in "Parse_review" method. In that case I ve a concatenated item. which has to be avoided.

Comment: You can use [`copy.copy` and `copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) to create copies of objects and work with those, instead of manipulating the original object over and over.